Importing ModuleNotFound: Python commpy module
I am having a little bit of a rough time trying to use the commpy module in Python 3.
I am using Python 3.11.9 | packaged by conda-forge in Spyder, with a Windows 11 computer. The problem is that when I try to run a script that runs perfectly on IDLE, in Linux, it gives me the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commpy'

The line raising the error is the following:
from commpy.filters import rrcosfilter

Any ideas to use it in Python 3?
Thanks in advance for your time!
I installed commpy with pip (pip install scikit-commpy) but it is still not working, and when I try to install it with miniconda (conda install veeresht::scikit-commpy) I get the following error:
Channels:
 - defaults
 - veeresht
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package scikit-commpy-0.3.0-np19py27_0 requires python 2.7*, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.12.* , which can be installed;
└─ scikit-commpy is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 2.7* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

